# How to make loop or another function to repeat the same for loop again and again?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

The content I am getting from Dmoz website. The `for loop` which I have made, I don't want to repeat it every time. Instead I want to make a way not to repeat with every function. There are many functions which I have created. I shared one just to show you that the `zip` is binding the values of names and finder. And I don't want `for loop` to be repeated in every function.

```
def parse_about(self, response):
    # do your stuff on second page
    items = response.meta['items']
    names = {'name1': 'Headings',
             'name2': 'Paragraphs',
             'name3': '3 Projects',
             'name4': 'About Dmoz',
             'name5': 'Languages',
             'name6': 'You can make a differnce', 
             'name7': 'Further Information'
             }

    finder = {'find1': 'h2::text , #mainContent h1::text',
              'find2': 'p::text',
              'find3': 'li~ li+ li b a::text , li:nth-child(1) b a::text',
              'find4': '.nav ul a::text , li:nth-child(2) b a::text',
              'find5': '.nav~ .nav a::text',
              'find6': 'dd::text , #about-contribute::text',
              'find7': 'li::text , #about-more-info a::text'
              }
    for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
        items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
        yield items
```

Comment: There is probably a way to do that, but at the moment it's a little unclear what the goal is.  Could you edit your post to give an example of the repetition you're trying to avoid, with more than one occurrence?

Comment: This is function and there are more functions which I created but the problem is the ```for loop``` which I have created, I have to apply in every function with same ```zipping``` and I don't want to repeat this ```for loop```. Is there any way to make just one loop for all the functions or will I have to make another special function just to loop all the functions. If so then please help with some code

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the current code works as expected and the other functions differ only by the contents of the `names` and `finder` dictionaries, you can abstract out the loop with a function like this:

```
def find_items(response, names, finder):
    items = response.meta['items']
    for name, find in zip(names.values(), finder.values()):
        items[name] = response.css(find).extract()
        yield items
```

Then if you are using Python 3.3 or higher, you can use a `yield from` statement in the calling functions like so:

```
yield from find_items(reponse, names1, finder1)
```

Comment: I have edited the code. It was my mistake of giving names of names1 and finder1. These are just names and finder.

Comment: The code in answer is correct. Add `find_items` function to class and edit your other functions in this way: `def parse_about(self, response): names1 = {...} finder1 = {...} yield from find_items(response, names1, finder1)`